Spring3 with Docker not able to auotwire the dependencies but in intellij, without docker, @Autowired is able to set the proper value
We are migrating to SpringBoot 3 from spring boot 2.6. In intellij every thing is working fine. I am able to call the rest api and it's returning the expected response.
But when I am running in docker container, class member variables are not getting initialised by @Autowired. It says ApplicationContext is null and Getting null Pointer exception.
Following are the exceptions:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.adobe.uppgatewayservice.repo.ServiceRepo.getEvents(String, String[])" because "<local7>.repo" is null
    at com.adobe.uppgatewayservice.resource.UPPGatewayAdminResource.getEventMetadatasByProvisioningId(UPPGatewayAdminResource.java:111)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:357)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)


java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(java.lang.Class)" because "applicationContext" is null
    at com.adobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionResponseHelper.findAppropriateResponseBuilder(AsrExceptionResponseHelper.java:104)
    at com.adobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionResponseHelper.buildResponse(AsrExceptionResponseHelper.java:90)
    at com.adobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionResponseHelper.buildResponse(AsrExceptionResponseHelper.java:69)
    at com.adobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionMapper.toResponse(AsrExceptionMapper.java:41)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processExceptionWithMapper(ServerRuntime.java:592)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.mapException(ServerRuntime.java:557)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestS

Our controller is defined as bellow:
@Path("/admin")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UPPGatewayAdminResource {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UPPGatewayAdminResource.class);

    @Autowired
    SLAStore slaStore;
    
    @Autowired
    SystemConfigStore systemConfigStore;
    
    @Autowired
    ServiceRepo repo;
    ........

We are using ServiceRepo repo in the method called, and getting Null Pointer exception.
Following are the container logs, I noticed that in log it's printing "Running with Spring Boot v0.1, Spring v0.1" which looks wierd.
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
upp-gateway-service-web-1  |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.7)
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:08.009 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] c.adobe.uppgatewayservice.Application    : Starting Application v0.1 using Java 17.0.10 with PID 1231 (/application.jar started by asruser in /etc/services-available/java)
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:08.025 GMT DEBUG requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] c.adobe.uppgatewayservice.Application    : Running with Spring Boot v0.1, Spring v0.1
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:08.026 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] c.adobe.uppgatewayservice.Application    : The following 1 profile is active: "test"
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.651 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.654 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.677 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17 ms. Found 0 Reactive Cassandra repository interfaces.
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.682 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.682 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.687 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 Cassandra repository interfaces.
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.695 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.697 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:09.710 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:10.021 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'asrJerseyBeanPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [com.adobe.asr.jersey.AsrJerseyBeanPostProcessorConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:10.038 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.adobe.asr-com.adobe.asr.autoconfigure.core.properties.AsrProperties' of type [com.adobe.asr.autoconfigure.core.properties.AsrProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:10.330 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:10.353 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:10.354 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:10.414 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
upp-gateway-service-web-1  | 2024-04-05 08:36:10.416 GMT  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 1231 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2341 m

Following is the intellij log which looks correct and spring version log is "Running with Spring Boot v3.0.7, Spring v6.0.9":
Starting Application using Java 17.0.10 with PID 99633 (/Users/ajaykumarverma/Documents/projects/originalProject/FG/upp-gateway/upp-gateway-service/target/classes started by ajaykumarverma in /Users/ajaykumarverma/Documents/projects/originalProject/FG/upp-gateway/upp-gateway-service)
2024-04-05 14:16:50.997 IST DEBUG requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] c.adobe.uppgatewayservice.Application    : Running with Spring Boot v3.0.7, Spring v6.0.9
2024-04-05 14:16:50.997 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] c.adobe.uppgatewayservice.Application    : The following 1 profile is active: "test"
2024-04-05 14:16:51.692 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-04-05 14:16:51.694 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-05 14:16:51.708 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11 ms. Found 0 Reactive Cassandra repository interfaces.
2024-04-05 14:16:51.710 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-04-05 14:16:51.710 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-05 14:16:51.714 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 Cassandra repository interfaces.
2024-04-05 14:16:51.721 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-04-05 14:16:51.721 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-05 14:16:51.730 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2024-04-05 14:16:51.938 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'asrJerseyBeanPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [com.adobe.asr.jersey.AsrJerseyBeanPostProcessorConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-04-05 14:16:51.950 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.adobe.asr-com.adobe.asr.autoconfigure.core.properties.AsrProperties' of type [com.adobe.asr.autoconfigure.core.properties.AsrProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-04-05 14:16:52.090 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-04-05 14:16:52.096 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-04-05 14:16:52.096 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2024-04-05 14:16:52.146 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-04-05 14:16:52.147 IST  INFO requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 99633 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1128 ms


Looks like you are doing things differently local and in the container. For starters I see @Path etc. which means you are using Jersey. Looks like you are running locally with an embedded container and in docker deploying to wildfly or glassfish or whatever, which will then manage the lifecycle and not spring.

Examine the logs when starting your Spring Boot application in the Docker container. Look for any warnings or errors related to component scanning, bean creation, or autowiring. That way you can what is running the application in the container.
Better still u can post your dockerFile here as well

@M.Deinum It's tomcat only in both places as you can see the attached logs.

@JUDE I have added the logs also, only major difference I am seeing in the log that in intellij it's printing "Running with Spring Boot v3.0.7, Spring v6.0.9 " while in container its printing "Running with Spring Boot v0.1, Spring v0.1" Which is very wierd.

Please post your Dockerfile

Thanks Everyone, Solution was following dependency:
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

